# How can I investigate HTML limitations in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code:

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" required />
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When you leave that input empty and then click on `submit` button, HTML throws:

> Please fill out this filed.

Also this is my new code:

```js
$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function(){
  $("input[type='text']:first-child").hide(100);
  $("input[type='text']:last-child").show(100);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" required />
    <br />
    <input type="text" required style="display:none;"/>
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

See? The process goes forward without throwing that error while that input is not filled. Anyway, how can I check are all required inputs filled in jQuery?

Noted that I can do that like this: `if ( $("input[type='text']:first-child).val() == "" ){}`, but in reality there are lots of inputs (about 21 ones) in the form.

Comment: A required field should not be hidden. In fact the alert message is also hidden but exists. You have to check if first child has value before hiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the validity of form controls through `checkValidity()` method, which returns `true` if the inputs are valid. However, if you invoke that on the form element, through `document.forms[0].checkValidity()`, it will validate the second input - which is still invisible, and return `false`  as it's not been filled yet.

So one of the things you could do would be to invoke the function on the first text input, through `$("input[type='text']:first-child")[0].checkValidity()` and if it returns true, then go ahead with the rest of the process.

```js
$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function(){
  if ($("input[type='text']:first-child")[0].checkValidity()) {
    $("input[type='text']:first-child").hide(100);
    $("input[type='text']:last-child").show(100);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" required />
    <br />
    <input type="text" required style="display:none;"/>
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

You can go a step further and rather than selecting specifically the first input, select all visible fields and invoke `checkValidity()` on them one after another.

```js
$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function(){
  if (checkValidityOfvisibleFields()) {
    $("input[type='text']:first-child").hide(100);
    $("input[type='text']:last-child").show(100);
  }
})

function checkValidityOfvisibleFields() {
  var isValid = true;
  $("input[type='text']:visible").each(function() {
    var isFieldValid = this.checkValidity();
    
    if(!isFieldValid) {
      isValid = false;
      return false; // Break.
    }
  });
  
  return isValid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" required />
    <br />
    <input type="text" required />
    <br />
    <input type="text" required />
    <br />
    <input type="text" required style="display:none;"/>
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```